# Set up and save ggplots to display later

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bunch of code that loops through a heap of data to produce a series of summary metrics.  I also want to generate a series of plots that I can then put into a grid of my choosing outside the loop.  Is this possible in R?

Here's a very simple example of what I mean

```
it = 0
while (it < 5){
  myX = runif(10)
  myY = runif(10)
  df = data.frame(x,y)
  plt[it] = ggplot(data = df, aes(myX, myY)) + geom_point(size = 2, color = "blue")
  it = it + 1
}
```

I then want to organise the plt into a grid

(although this does not seem to produce the plots, not sure why)

I would then be able to display each of the plots, put them in a grid, organise them etc. by calling the plt[2] or whatever.  I'm very new to ggplot and only a basic R user, so apologies if I'm missing the obvious.  Not even sure what language to use to search for this.

Also happy to be told this is a bad approach and there's a better way to create the plots.  I want to do it outside the loop as I want to examine the results before deciding how to arrange them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the results in a list. To correct your `while` loop you can do :

```
library(ggplot2)
plt <- vector('list', 4)
it = 1
while (it < 5){
  myX = runif(10)
  myY = runif(10)
  df = data.frame(myX,myY)
  plt[[it]] = ggplot(data = df, aes(myX, myY)) + 
                     geom_point(size = 2, color = "blue")
  it = it + 1
}
```

---

Another approach would be to write a function and call it `n` times with `replicate`.

```
create_plot <- function() {
  myX = runif(10)
  myY = runif(10)
  df = data.frame(myX,myY)
  ggplot(data = df, aes(myX, myY)) + geom_point(size = 2, color = "blue")
}
plt <- replicate(4, create_plot(), simplify = FALSE)
```

You could access individual plots with `plt[[1]]`, `plt[[2]]` and so on.