# Displaying saved ggplots in a grid when saved in a matrix in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I have created plots using a loop and saved them in a matrix ([see my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64709801/2613271)).  I now want to arrange the plots in a grid using plot_grid or similar.  Is there a simple way to call the matrix of saved plots?  I want the resulting grid of plots to match the layout of the matrix.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)


# create and save the plots to the matrix
plt <- vector('list', 10)
plt <- matrix(plt, nrow = 5, ncol = 2)

it = 1
while (it < 5){
  myX = runif(10)
  myY = runif(10)
  df = data.frame(myX,myY)
  plt[[it, 1]] = ggplot(data = df, aes(myX, myY)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2, color = "blue")
  plt[[it, 2]] = ggplot(data = df, aes(myX, myY)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2, color = "red")
  it = it + 1
}  

# display the plots in a grid that matches the matrix format
a1<- plt[[1,1]]
b1 <-plt[[1,2]]

a2<- plt[[2,1]]
b2 <-plt[[2,2]]

plot_grid(a1, b1, a2, b2, ncol = 2)
```

What I have above works, but I have had to assign each of the elements of the matrix to a variable, and then manually call all the variables in order in the `plot_grid` command.  I am trying to find a way to avoid this.  I have just showed a grid of 4 here - I have many more plots in my real problem.

I have tried using `plot_grid(plt, ncol = 2)`, which gives the error "Cannot convert object of class matrixarray into a grob."  I have also tried `mylist = c(plt[[1,1]], plt[[1,2]], plt[[2,1]], plt[[2,2]])` and `plot_grid(mylist, ncol = 2)` but get the same error.

I also tried to use `do.call("grid.arrange", c(plt, ncol = 2))` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10706828/2613271) but could not get that working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing non-atomic objects inside of matrices can be very messy. So first, gather the plots you want in a normal list, then, when passing the list to `plot_grid`, be sure do to so via the `plotlist=` parameter

```
mylist = list(plt[[1,1]], plt[[1,2]], plt[[2,1]], plt[[2,2]])
plot_grid(plotlist=mylist, ncol=2)
```

If you wanted to plot all the values, then you would just need to transpose the list because the list is stored in column order but is plotted in row order by default

```
plot_grid(plotlist=t(plt), ncol=2)
```

The `do.call` would have worked if you had a plain list and not a matrix list. YOu could have a helper function to remove the matrix part from the list when trying to plot. For example

```
undim <- function(x) {dim(x) <- NULL; x}
do.call("plot_grid", c(undim(plt), ncol = 2))
```

But here the `plotlist=` parameter is definitely the better way to dg.

Answer (score 1):

In line with @MrFlick I would suggest to store your plots in a list which could be easily passed to `plot_grid` via argument `plotlist`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)

it = 1
plt <- list()
while (it < 5){
  myX = runif(10)
  myY = runif(10)
  df = data.frame(myX,myY)
  p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(myX, myY)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2, color = "blue")
  p2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(myX, myY)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2, color = "red")
  
  plt <- c(plt, list(p1, p2))
  it <- it + 1
}  

# display the plots in a grid that matches the matrix format
plot_grid(plotlist = plt, ncol = 2)
```

[image]